# Regex para validar data yyyy/mm/dd?

Tags: javascript, regex

Já testei várias expressões, mas não obtive o resultado desejado.

Como posso validar a data para `yyyy/mm/dd` ?

Comment: vc quer apenas validar se o texto é uma data valida ou apenas o formato?

Comment: Preciso verificar se em um texto existe uma data nesse formato

Comment: Com baras a separar os campos ou pode ser com "-", ou outros?

Comment: Seria interessante aceitar "-" ou "/" como separador. Para verificar se a data é válida, seria interessante usar a regex, ou uma função para isso? por exemplo, 0000/00/00 -> nao valida.

Comment: Só lembrando que é um forma não muito usual para validar data, somente regex não confirmar se a data é válida ou não, tome cuidado com isso.

Comment: @João Você se refere  a data em relação ao tempo atual, ou ao formato ou aos 2 ?

Comment: @MagicHat eu falo em data válida mesmo, independente do tempo. O formato em si você consegue até validar, mas, o valor da data sendo válida ou não é melhor usar alguma biblioteca como por exemplo http://momentjs.com/ para javascript é a melhor! O legal que ela confere também formatos ...

Comment: @João ah saquei...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6pgh0cz3/1/). Desta forma consegue validar a data nos formatos: `yyyy-mm-dd , yyyy/mm/dd , yyyy.mm.dd`

```
function data_valida(date)
{
    var matches = /(\d{4})[-.\/](\d{2})[-.\/](\d{2})/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) {
        return false;
    }
    var dia = matches[3];
    var mes = matches[2] - 1;
    var ano = matches[1];
    var data = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
    return data.getDate() == dia && data.getMonth() == mes && data.getFullYear() == ano;
}

alert(data_valida('2016.05.26'));
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: De nada. Ainda bem que ajudou

Comment: Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui para entender como funciona esse "matches", pois preciso validar uma data neste formato: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. Sei que este post já é meio antigo, mas se alguém puder me orientar eu agradeço.

Answer (score -1):

Função em javascript para validar mascara e valor da data em formato brasileiro.

```js
if(validateDate("27/04/2009"))
  console.log("OK");
else
   console.log("Data incorreta");

function validateDate(data) {
        // Ex: 10/01/1985
        var regex = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}";
        var dtArray = data.split("/");

        if (dtArray == null)
            return false;

        // Checks for dd/mm/yyyy format.
        var dtDay= dtArray[0];
        var dtMonth = dtArray[1];
        var dtYear = dtArray[2];

        if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12)
            return false;
        else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay> 31)
            return false;
        else if ((dtMonth==4 || dtMonth==6 || dtMonth==9 || dtMonth==11) && dtDay ==31)
            return false;
        else if (dtMonth == 2)
        {
            var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
            if (dtDay> 29 || (dtDay ==29 && !isleap))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```